# Error in my "x.cs"

Tags: c#, compilation

I was writing this (very) simple C# code to send to my Raspberry Pi with Mono. New to this,i get error

> ("} expected") & ("Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file
>   expected")

Can you guys help me with compiling this? (btw, running mcs on mono in linux told me to add `static public void Main () {}` into the .cs file.

```
using System;

public class helloWorld
{
    public helloWorld()
    {
        static public void Main ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! You´re welcome m8!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the beginning of a constructor, but without the closing brace.

Comment: Why is there a static Main *inside* the constructor?

Comment: The declaration of `Main()` is placed inside your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the static `Main` function inside your constructor method.

Change this to:

```
using System;

public class helloWorld
{
    public helloWorld()
    {
        // ...
    }

    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World! You´re welcome m8!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. Works like a charm. Mono compiles the .cs just perfect. :D

Comment: @OscarAndersson glad that worked for you. Two remarks: (1) please read ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (2) try to use a good tutorial, and look at some examples to learn the c# language and try solving these types of things yourself instead of asking this quickly on SO. You will learn much more and quicker that way.

Comment: yeah sorry for that, i`m a new user so i could not actually mark your answer, i can in a few minutes doe.
I´ve also ordered a book in C# and my tech-class in programming starts after the summer break.
I'm Hoping to kick it off with the book and then attend the class. In school its still very basic with HTML and then later C# .NET XNA so im looking forward to that.
Ive bet you could see this already but this is in fact my second C# class ever. :) Liking it already!
Thanks Alex. Great regards Oscar Andersson Sweden.

Comment: @OscarAndersson, programming can be loads of fun. It is a good thing that you are starting to learn by yourself before your class starts. Practicing, and looking at examples that are just a tiny bit beyond your current level of comprehension, breaking things and figuring them out yourself (even if that takes a while and can be frustrating at the time)  are good ways to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace MyFirstProgram 
{
    public class helloWorld
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! You´re welcome m8!");
        }
    }
}
```

You also had a method within a method which isn't allowed. The namespace isn't technically required, but its a good practice to start using them when you create larger projects.

Comment: Ahha, hmm okay, gotta have to look closer on namespaces. thank you for taking your time. :)